# Как найти код для удаления уведомления о куках?

Tags: wordpress

Как убрать уведомление о куках на сайте https://shashki.biz , сайт работает на ворд пресс. Какой участок кода удалить для этого? Уведомление где-то кодом выводится.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getcookie(a) {var b = new RegExp(a+'=([^;]){1,}');var c = b.exec(document.cookie);if(c) c = c[0].split('=');else return false;return c[1] ? c[1] : false;}

var gg = getcookie('politica');


if (!(gg)) {
document.getElementsByClassName('cookie')[0].style.display = 'block';
}   


button_cookie.onclick = function() {
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 20000000 * 1000);
document.getElementsByClassName('cookie')[0].style.display = 'none';
document.cookie = "politica=true; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
};  
</script>
```

Comment: нет, это не гугловское уведомление

Comment: Да я не правильно сказал. НА сайте скрипт присутствует кастомный

Comment: отредактировал соощение